# Nginx forward tls based on domain

Tags: nginx, proxy, tls

Is it possible to forward some tls requests based on their domain name to another server (via nginx)?

I have a public nginx server which serves some pages via http and https (in the image b.com). Now I have a VM only reachable via the nginx server, running an apache server. Can I tell my nginx server to forward request (to a.com) to the 10.x.x.x server without touching the tls? Through SNI nginx should know which domain is requested?

I don't have the certificates for a.com on the public server.

[image: Problem]

Comment: Doesn't seem like nginx has the capability at this time. I believe it terminates TLS before it gets to the vhost/rev.proxy logic. There are a couple sni proxy projects on github, but I haven't tried any.

Comment: I really doubt Nginx will ever propose this feature: this requires that your nginx "proxy" decrypts the ssl/tls data... You should configure ssl/tls only in b.com for both a.com and b.com

Comment: @moebius_eye Why should it decrypt the tls?

Comment: Could you provide the `nginx` config you are currently using?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, NGINX cannot forward requests this way: it always manage the ssl handshake by itself.

However, **haproxy** and **sniproxy** seems to do the job, according to the answers given in this thread:
[Can a Reverse Proxy use SNI with SSL pass through?](https://serverfault.com/questions/625362/can-a-reverse-proxy-use-sni-with-ssl-pass-through)